# How can i enable selecting a date from Calendar View Date Picker in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, sdk, calendar, datepicker

I am trying to do simle app and i need to enable selecting a date from Calendar View Date Picker. Does iPhone SDK has such UI Controller ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It has the UIDatePicker:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html

Which looks like this:
http://www.llamagraphics.com/files/imagecache/full_width_one_sidebar/inline-images/better.png

Comment: thanks, but was looking for calendar view data picker. Looks there is no SDK component yet. will try to find custom one.